# understanding X keyboard mappings, audio keys and fluxbox

Tags: audio, x11, keyboard-events

So, I'm trying to set up fluxbox to work with my Dell keyboard which has a bunch of extra keys on it for web browsing and audio control.

I did this in my .fluxbox/keys file, and it's mostly working to control cmus.

```
# Music in cmus
XF86AudioPlay :Exec cmus-remote --pause
XF86AudioPause :Exec cmus-remote --pause
XF86AudioStop :Exec cmus-remote --stop
XF86AudioNext :Exec cmus-remote --next
XF86AudioPrev :Exec cmus-remote --prev
```

But, the stop key doesn't work. So I use showkey on it...

```
keycode 166 press
keycode 166 release
```

and it tells me that the stop key is keycode 166. According to xmodmap...

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 166
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
```

that is XF86Back, but mapping that in my keys file doesn't work either. More disturbing, the play/pause key, which is already working, is supposedly keycode 164, which xmodmap says is...

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 164
keycode 164 = XF86Favorites NoSymbol XF86Favorites
```

when I expectted it to be XF86AudioPlay, which is supposedly...

```
xmodmap -pke | grep AudioPlay
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
```

one of those. So...

...what's going on? Why is play/pause working if it's the wrong keycode, and is it the wrong keycode? Being a Dell keyboard, I expect all kinds of problems, since Dell in their infinite wisdom always liked to deviate from standards.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This is not a good place to ask such question, something like askubuntu or [unix.se] could be better places. Anyway, `showkey` has nothing to do with X11, try `xev`.

Comment: Yeah, I did but it's not very helpful. For all of the audio keys it lists a "KeymapNotify event", and I don't know how to read the output. For all other keys I get a "KeyPress event" followed by a "KeyRelease event", with the keysym resolved to a name.

Comment: You need to move the pointer inside the small square and press keys. It should print something like `KeyPress event` and then `keycode 172 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay)`

Comment: If you don't see KeyPress events, then you probably have global shortcuts bound to these keys and you cannot really intercept them unless you remove these shortcuts.